# Javascript , event handler is always called, even if the event is not raised

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

i have the following code which extends the JQuery and adds a method to the JQuery:

```
$.fn.attachWithMessage = function () {
  $(this).focusin(showMessage());
}

function showMessage() {
    alert('hi');
}
```

so I can use that code as follows :

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="textbox" />
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#textbox").attachWithMessage ();
});
```

when I load the page for the first time, a message box shows up with ('hi') message.

even if I didn't click in the text box.

I also tried the click event, and the message still shows automatically.

any ideas ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that when you pass `showMessage()` as a parameter to `focusin`, the function `showMessage` is **executed** and the **return value** is passed to `focusin`.

Instead you need to pass a reference to the function (without the paranthesis).

Use the following code to extend:

```
$.fn.attachWithMessage = function () {   
  $(this).focusin(showMessage); 
}
```

Working example@ http://jsfiddle.net/eXEP5/

**EDIT:**
If you want to pass a parameter to showMessage then try this:

```
$.fn.attachWithMessage = function () {   
  var param1 = "Some Param";
  $(this).focusin(function(){
     showMessage(param1); //Make sure showMessage is modified accordingly for the parameters.
  }); 
}
```

Comment: but what if I want to pass a parameter to showMessage when the event is fired ???

Answer (score 2):

just remove the parenthesis

```
$(this).focusin(showMessage());
```

should be

```
$(this).focusin(showMessage);
```

Hope this helps