# Backbone.js event always activated

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Javascript , event handler is always called, even if the event is not raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941622/javascript-event-handler-is-always-called-even-if-the-event-is-not-raised)

I'm new to Backbone.js and I have an issue with an event.

In my appView.js, I have just this :

```
var languagesView = new app.LanguagesView();
```

And this languagesView.js :

```
var app = app || {};

$(function() {

app.LanguagesView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.on("foo", this.fooFunction());
    },

    fooFunction: function() {
        console.log("---FOO----")
    }

});
});
```

I have no trigger in my app and I don't understand why the `fooFunction` is always called when I open my page. Is there something I have misunderstood about the events?

Comment: Because you *are* calling the function... by the function-invoking parentheses `()`.

Comment: Ohoh, thanks ! God forgive me!

Comment: @RobW I think this question is different enough since the reference is solely about jQuery while this one is presented on top of a Backbone layer, specifically how the Backbone.Events module works. Also, your comment looks like an answer... Collect your prize! :-D

Comment: @orangewarp The problem is library-independent. The problem is identical, and the duplicate already explains the solution very well. A closre-as-duplicate fits in this case.